# Text within SVG textPath not visible from iOS browsers

Tags: svg, mobile, cross-browser, mobile-safari

I am trying to display text on a curved path within an SVG that will load nicely on mobile browsers. I'm using the SVG `textPath` element (which [MDN claims is widely supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/textPath#Browser_compatibility)) and I have the following simple example:

```css
html,body,svg { height:100% }
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <path
    id="MyPath"
    fill="none"
    stroke="red"
    d="M10,90 Q90,90 90,45 Q90,10"
  />
  <text>
    <textPath href="#MyPath">
      Sample Text
    </textPath>
  </text>
</svg>
```

My **desktop browsers** display things nicely as:

[image: working example]

However **on my iPhone I only see the red line** and the text is missing.

[image: non-working example]

I've tried in Safari iOS 11.3, Chrome iOS 67, Firefox iOS 12.1, all with the same results.

I would love to figure out how to get that curved tex to display on within the browsers on my iPhone. Thanks!

Comment: xlink:href rather than href

Comment: xlink:href is deprecated - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/xlink:href